# Change Multiple Data Entries in Different Excel Sheets

Tags: excel

I need to change the data in multiple cell sheets at the same time. The problem is, they aren't the same cell and they need to be automatically updated. For instance, I need to edit a value in sheet 1 A1 that will be automatically updated in sheet 2 B1. Is there some way to easily change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sheet2 B1, type in the formula `=Sheet1!A1`